Regression with small sample size - LASSO or remove variables?
I'm trying to run a regression, but I only have 14 observations, each being a different city in the US. My dependent variable is the total number of trips per capita, and my explanatory variables are demographics, city characteristics and weather variables. I have 26 variables in total, many of which are correlated. When I run an OLS regression with 4 or 5 of the variables, which I picked based on scatter plots which seem to indicate a relationship and aren't significantly correlated to one another, some of them do come out as significant, but it's my understanding that as a rule of thumb for the number of observations I have I should only have one, maybe two, explanatory variables at a push. The problem with this however, is that essentially renders the study pointless. I've read a few things about LASSO regression and it seems like it could help. On the other hand, I have no idea how to apply it in Stata.
Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
